# What does this error mean? Xcode: "Mach-O Librarian.... Log complete" Coreplot

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, core-plot

I have an warning in Xcode - here is a screen shot.

Clicking it tells me nothing, I don't know how to make it go away!

To be honest, I think my title for this question is not very good and given that people might come across this when looking for other error messages some clarification on what I should even call this question would be handy.

[image]

Comment: Looking more closely at it I see it says "-all_load invalid" which is something I think I had to do to get Coreplot working. This might be the answer to the question. I'll leave it though, I'm interested in seeing what the heck this "Activity Log Complete" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-all_load` linker flag is not allowed in Xcode 5.1. Either remove it from the build settings in the Core Plot project or upgrade to Core Plot 1.5.1 (or later) that already has this fix.